# redirect to return url after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a link in my razor view like this:

```
 <a href="Home/Login?ReturnUrl=Disputes/Index"> disputes</a>
```

Inside my login's action method, I am using this:

```
 public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) {
   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null)
         returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);

   if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
   {
      ViewBag.ReturnURL = returnUrl;
   }

   return View();
 }
```

In view I am using this:

```
 @Html.Hidden("returnUrl",@Request.QueryString)
```

Then in post action method:

```
 public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
 {
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      if (membershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password, model.Type))
      {
         formsAuthenticationService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
         SetUserInfo(model.UserName);

         string decodedUrl = "";
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl);

         if (Url.IsLocalUrl(decodedUrl))                    
            return Redirect(decodedUrl);
         else
            return Redirect("Home", Index);

      }
   }
 }
```

It is redirecting to:`/Disputes/Index` but it should go to `myApp/Disputes/Index` where the url with query string is like this. `/myApp/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=/Disputes/Index`

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: try using <a href="Home/Login?ReturnUrl=/Disputes/Index"> disputes</a>
(with the "/") or even try no query string to test the UrlReferrer method.

Comment: @Oliver: I tried without querystring and it didnt work ...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I use a combination of the above suggestion and `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the previous location:

```
    public ActionResult LogOn(string returnUrl)
    {
        //So that the user can be referred back to where they were when they click logon
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null)
            returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnURL = returnUrl;
        }
        return View();
    }
```

This way I don't have to put the location in the `ActionLink`.

I populate a hidden field in the login page using the `ViewBag.ReturnURL`.  Then in the Login HTTPPost `ActionResult` I redirect the user to the location in the hidden field (if there is one):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)
    {
        //returnURL needs to be decoded
        string decodedUrl = "";
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
            decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl);

        //Login logic...

        if (Url.IsLocalUrl(decodedUrl))
        {
            return Redirect(decodedUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I used hidden field in login page and now I can see returnurl value in login action method like this: ReturnUrl=%2fDisputes%2fIndex but It fails here:  if (Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl) && returnUrl.Length > 1 && returnUrl.StartsWith("/")
                        && !returnUrl.StartsWith("//") && !returnUrl.StartsWith("/\\"))
                        return Redirect(returnUrl);

Comment: in my login post action, I have:                      string decodedUrl = "";
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl))
                        decodedUrl = Server.UrlDecode(returnUrl);
                    if (Url.IsLocalUrl(decodedUrl))
                    {
                        return Redirect(decodedUrl);
                    }
This works for me.  Is the URL definitely valid?

Comment: it is redirecting to this: /Disputes/Index but it should go to myApp/Disputes/Index where as the url with querystring is like this. /myApp/Home/Login?ReturnUrl=/Disputes/Index

Comment: Why store the value in the ViewBag at all when it is done automatically by the framework? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20149890/2093880

Answer (score 8):

In this case you could have your LogOn action take a returnUrl parameter and if it is not empty, instead of redirecting to Home/Index you could return `Redirect(returnUrl);`. Take a look at the default AccountController generated by VS when you create a new project. It does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have this written but still returnUrl is empty in action method. did i create wrong return url in href ? Please suggest

Comment: You might need to url encode the value: `<a href="Home/Login?ReturnUrl=Disputes%2FIndex">disputes</a>`.

Comment: no, samething after encoding: returnurl in login action method is null where as querystring as returnurl like this:  public ActionResult Login(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)  and /Home/Login?ReturnUrl=Disputes%2FIndex

Answer (score 7):

If the `ReturnURL` is `null`, make sure you are calling the action method from the view as follows:

```
// FormMethod.post is optional
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    // login view html
}
```

Account controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Yeah, its important to get this right. For me, the anonymous object setting a class in my HTML was being used as the anon object for the route values, so ReturnUrl wasn't coming back, instead I was seeing 'class' in the query params. Best to check the final rendered markup. I use this:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("BetaLogin", "Authentication", new { ReturnUrl = this.Request.Params["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "o-box-section" }))`

Comment: Setting the return url on the form worked perfectly for me with minimal code changes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
        //Utilities         
        public static ReturnUrl GetReturnUrlValues(string returnUrl)
        {
            //0:Action,1:Controller,2:Area:,3:Id
            ReturnUrl vm = new ReturnUrl();
            using (TBBSEntities context = new TBBSEntities())
            {
                if (returnUrl != null && returnUrl.Length > 10)
                {
                    var counterValue = returnUrl.Split('/');
                    vm.Action = counterValue[0];
                    vm.Controller = counterValue[1];
                    vm.Area = counterValue[2] == "0" ? "" : counterValue[2] ;
                    vm.Id = Convert.ToInt32(counterValue[3]);
                    vm.NullStatus = true;
                    return vm;
                }
                vm.NullStatus = false;
                return vm;
            }
        }

        //Controller
        var transformUrl = Utilities.GetReturnUrlValues(returnUrl);
            if (transformUrl.NullStatus)
            {
            return RedirectToAction(transformUrl.Action, transformUrl.Controller,
                    new { area = transformUrl.Area, id = transformUrl.Id });
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Action", "Controller", new { area = "Area", Id});


        //View
        var returnUrl = "Action/Controller/Area/" + @Model.Id;
```

Comment: Try explaining your answer as it will be useful for others.