# return url is not working after login

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on asp.net MVC 3 application. One home page of the application, there are some links which redirect to login page like this:

```
 <a href="Home/Login?returnUrl=/Disputes/Index"> Disputes </a>
```

login action method is like this:

```
  public ActionResult Login() 
        {
return view();
        }
```

on Login view I have a partial view like this:

```
 @Html.Partial("_LogOn", new LogOnModel { Type = LogOnTypeEnum.Obligor })
```

and _LogOn partial is like this:

at the top it is like this:

```
@{
    string retUrl = "";
    if (ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer != null)
    {
        retUrl =
          ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
    }             
}
```

and form looks like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LogOn", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off", id = "frmLogin", Type = 2, model = this.Model, returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
```

and finally logon method of Account controller:

```
 public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model, string returnUrl)

{
// I want to redirect to localhost:2304//myapp/returnurl but returnurl is empty

}
```

I am following this example ( it is not using partial view as I am using)

http://visualstudiounleashed.com/mikesnell/post/2011/08/16/Using-the-ASPNET-MVC-3-Logon-returnUrl-Parameter.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [redirect to return url after login](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554115/redirect-to-return-url-after-login)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use UrlReferrer to get the return URL. Instead, take it in as an argument to your GET action method:

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl) 
{
    return View(new LogOnModel { ReturnUrl = returnUrl });
}
```

Your LogOnModel will have to have a ReturnUrl property, we use this:

```
[HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
```

Then, when user posts the form, make sure that the ReturnUrl comes into your POST action method:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.ReturnUrl)

public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
{
    // on logon success, redirect to model.ReturnUrl
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. The last Logon method's model.returnUrl property has /Disputes/Index

Comment: Good answer, but why does it no longer work by passing the returnUrl into the post to Index(LogonModel, returnUrl)?

Comment: Usually, when you are taking a LoginModel, it's during an HTTP POST. Sending a returnUrl is usually done via HTTP GET. Why not just add a string ReturnUrl property to your LoginModel?

Comment: I use the same method now and it works great. Note that it used to work the old way (i.e. without having the ReturnUrl in the model object) until I added AutoComplete=off to my login Form, Username field and Pwd field.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in MVC 5, so it may not help with MVC 3.

It was because I was trying to code for returnUrl, but it's already configured in your controller.  If you look in your Login Action, there is a redirectToLocal attribute that redirects the action to your local account controller login action.  All you have to do is put the AUTHORIZE class above your Controller Action, thus:

```
<Authorize>
    Function Create() As ActionResult
        Return View()
    End Function
```