# By clicking submit button when form fields are not validated ReturnUrl from browser vanished

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

By clicking submit button when form fields are not validated ReturnUrl from browser vanished.

Before clicking submit button browser seems look like.

[image]

After clicking submit button(while form fields are not validated till) browser seems look like.

[image]

How to maintain same browsing address after clicking submit button as after login it should be redirect to that page.?

Here is the Action code

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
            model.UserName,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), // value of time out property
            false, // Value of IsPersistent property
            String.Empty,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
            string encTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);
            HttpCookie faCookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encTicket);
            Response.Cookies.Add(faCookie);
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Home"));
        }
        else
        {
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: When validation fails, are you reassigning the value? e.g. `if(!ModelState.IsValid) { ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;...`

Comment: No @stephen.? But it is happening before calling to Action. I am going to update my question please check it now

Comment: When you say _"  before calling to Action.."_ do you mean that its not hitting the method at all

Comment: yes i think so :( because in my point of view it is all done by jqueryval and jquery before validation may be i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: Put a break point on the first line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and check.

Comment: Yes it is as you say... thanks for that now tell me how maintain return url please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you view has

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })) { ...
```

Then when validation fails, you need to re-assign the value in you action method

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
  ....
}
else
{
  // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
  ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
  ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl; // Add this line
  return View();
}
```

Comment: Stephen...
my view has this line.
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "customForm",ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))

Comment: Thats OK - my answer will still work, the key issue is the `..ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl..` Its value is assigned when you are redirected to this page for authentication, but you need to reassign it when you return the view because validation failed

Comment: i do the same as you suggest me but problem is that. returnUrl is coming null to action that't why it is not assigning to Viewbag.ReturnUrl. don't know why...

Comment: If i write this line.
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
it works for me but it is neccassary to assign id to form i manage css with that id..

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you using the wrong overload. It should be `@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "customForm" }))

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at the `AccountController` at the `public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)` method.

You can check out this SO article: [How am I supposed to use ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123612/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-returnurl-viewbag-returnurl-in-mvc-4)

Comment: thanks for your answer please check my question i updated it.