# Asp.net MVC 4 Authorize Login Redirect 302 Missing ReturnUrl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

When navigating to http://localhost:62030/Home/About and the Home controller includes the [Authorize] attribute the app correctly returns a 302 redirect to http://localhost:62030/Account/Login but w/o a ReturnUrl instead of http://localhost:62030/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2FHome%2FAbout
This seems to have started recently however I'm not aware of the cause.  When creating a new mvc project the redirect properly returns a redirect along with the ReturnUrl.  Where has the ReturnUrl gone?

Comment: I guess you are using identity, can you add your controller code which contains redirect url

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. This will aid in providing a possible solution.

Comment: The only auth related code in the controller is [Authorize].  I don't believe the problem is the AccountController because based on the chrome/network trace the accountcontroller is never receiving the return url in the redirect from the controller with the [Authorize] attribute.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You should be sure that you are using ReturnUrl in controller and view

```
Html.BeginForm("YourLogin", "Account", new {ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] })


[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult YourLogin(LoginInputModel model, string ReturnUrl) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the form authentication since ASP.NET MVC template is using Forms authentication.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
```

You can also refer the link:[Return URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123612/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-returnurl-viewbag-returnurl-in-mvc-4)

Answer (score 0):

Due to the way the Authorization Filters work ( [Authorize] Works as a Filter )

[image: Filter Layer]

you would never receive the request in HomeController.

To be using [Authorize] you're probably using Identity as Authentication/Authorization Middleware.

You should define the LoginPath correctly in your web.config.