# ASP.Net MVC redirects to "/" instead of specified action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this method in my controller to handle the submission of credentials for login.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginForm form)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = userService.Login(form); // determine if the form data authenticates a valid user
        if (user != null)
        {
            // OMITTED: Indicate correct credentials.
            if (System.String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(form.returnUrl) || (form.returnUrl == "/"))
            {
                var outbound = RedirectToAction("defaultAction", "defaultController");
                return outbound;
            }
            return Redirect(form.returnUrl);
        }
        // OMITTED: Indicate incorrect credentials.
        return View(form);
    }
    // OMITTED: Indicate improper form input
    return View(form);
}
```

IntelliTrace reports that the event right after "return outbound" is `ASP.Net: Redirect to "/"`. This is clearly incorrect; it should be `defaultController/defaultAction`. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

**Update 1:** Route configuration:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "defaultController", action = "defaultAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554115/redirect-to-return-url-after-login

Comment: Please show your route configuration.

Comment: Added route configuration.

Comment: So you've placed a breakpoint and confirmed that you actually hit `return outbound;` ?

Comment: Yes. (End of answer.)

Comment: Does the page load as expected, and you're only concerned about the url, or is the issue that the wrong page is loading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected.  Since you are redirecting to `defaultController/defaultAction`, and you have those configured as the defaults in your route config, MVC uses the url `/` to reference the default controller and action.

If you want to use the url `/defaultController/defaultAction`, you will need to do your redirect differently, specifically don't use `RedirectToAction`.

```
var outbound = Redirect("defaultController/defaultAction");
return outbound;
```

Alternatively, change your route config to use a different default action, then your code will generate the url you expect.

Comment: Or just `Redirect("/");`.